# Download PDFfrom Xamarin Android webview / MVC FileContentResult

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, pdf, webview, xamarin.android

I'm getting my PDF from a third party tool and then returning a FileContentResult.  From my laptops browser this downloads the PDF perfectly.

If I access the page, that has the download button on it, when it is in a Xamarin webview it doesn't do anything.  If I do an view.Context.StartActivity(intent); to pop open the pdf from outside the Xamarin app it sends me to my login page for the app.

```
    public FileContentResult DownloadPDF(decimal? id, decimal? id2)
    {
        // getting the pdf from third party tool
        var token = new Token(id.ToString(), UserInfo.Branch.ToString());
        token.GetToken();
        var download = new PDFDownload();
        var response = download.DownloadPDF(token.Token);
        var bytesArray = response.RawBytes;

        var ms = new MemoryStream(bytesArray);
        var result = new FileContentResult(bytesArray, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = id.ToString().Trim() + ".pdf"
        };

        return result;
    }
```

I've tried placing the PDF inside an iframe and it works on the local browser but not within the webview.

I've also tried using https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=, but apparently this doesn't work when the view is returning a FileContentResult.

Has anyone successfully gotten this to work?

Comment: @J Hunt: Did you find any solution for this?